# How to parse keyword IPTC from image using PHP?

Tags: php, image, image-processing, iptc

I have image with keyword. I can not extract keywords using IPTC. Did somebody found a way to retrieve the keyword phrases? How to approach the result? This code i found somewhere on forum.

```
 <?php function output_iptc_data( $image_path ) {
$size = getimagesize ( $image_path, $info);
if(is_array($info)) {
    $iptc = iptcparse($info["APP13"]);
    foreach (array_keys($iptc) as $s) {
        $c = count ($iptc[$s]);
        for ($i=0; $i <$c; $i++)
        {
            echo $s.' = '.$iptc[$s][$i].'<br>';
        }
    }
} } output_iptc_data('IMGP4053m.jpg'); ?>
```

Comment: python in the title but not tagged, php example, so what language did you want?

Comment: Sorry @Dagon, wrong edit question from old draft. I need php for parse the keywords. Thanks.

Comment: See [making IPTC data searchable](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1417138/834309).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@kuslahne please check my library: https://ibudasov.github.io/php7-iptc-manager/

Seems like it does everything you need.

```
// import the Manager class
use iBudasov\Iptc\Manager;

// ... and instantiate it!
$manager = Manager::create();

$manager->loadFile('./IMGP4053m.jpg');

$allTheTagsInTheImage = $manager->getTags();
```