# IPTC Data Management Library

Tags: php, image, jpeg, exif, iptc

I've written a fairly extensive script which manages images.

PHP imaging libraries strip meta data by default. So embedded data (like keywords, descriptions, author, etc) are gone. I've written a fairly extensive image management system, but sadly the IPTC management is still lacking much.

In the past I've written much of my own functions, but now I'd like to use a library which:

1. Easily retrieves info, typically into an array.
2. Can embed info easily.

Having looked around, I can't seem to find a modern or complete package which:

1. Is reasonably lightweight.
2. Is geared toward this specifically.

**If anyone knows any classes or sets of functions available somewhere, that would be great. I've looked everywhere and cannot find one.**

Thanks for any help. I have searched and cannot find a decent library.

Comment: following answer may help to solve your issue.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417138/making-iptc-data-searchable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much research, the best I could find is this old script here:

http://www.ozhiker.com/electronics/pjmt/index.html

It needs much updating, but generally works well.

Comment: That's true , I have been in search for this. Although its a very old library, works fine on PHP 5.4. May be it should be forked to new functions and methods. Many thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has some IPTC functionality by default:

- with [`getimagesize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) you can get additional info about images,
- with [`iptcparse()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iptcparse.php) you can parse IPTC data from info (which comes from `getimagesize()`),
- with [`iptcembed()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iptcembed.php) you can embed IPTC data into a jpeg file.

Comment: Yes, but I'm looking for a library which simplifies this. Those functions are quite finicky when it comes to keywords and such.